# SSRS 2017 report rendering issue when sending email to groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I develop a report using SSRS 2017 and scheduled an email rendering the data into email body. If a send just to me I get the email with no problem. if a scheduled to a group the email will be received with no data.

It is some limitation of SSRS?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Are all the recipients on the same exchange server as yourself and using the same mail client? It could be that the client they use isn't handling the embedded report elements as well as your own, if not.

Comment: Hi @C-Sway, all recipients are using the same email server. I cannot know if all are using the same mail client, but I am in the mail group and if I send just for me I receive the report correctly but if I send to the group I receive the email but with no data.

Comment: SSRS does not care about the type of recipient (group or single user). Check the parameter settings for your second subscription.

Comment: Does your report display correctly when you try to view the report for the same group with the data for the group?

Comment: Hi @Wolfgang Kais  I am using the same subscription, only changing the email address. If I use directly my email I receive with no problems. If I use the group email, I received the email with no data.

Comment: Hi @Hannover Fist, the only thing that change is the receiver email address from the subcription.

Comment: Do you use a "comment" in your subscription that contains some HTML/CSS Code? If so, try to remove that. If not, contact your email administrators to check for delivery restrictions for the distribution list.

Comment: Hi everyone... There has some issue on the server. I have done a roolback and the problem has solve. I do not know what happened :(